# In need of help of with a while loop program

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm a novice programmer is looking to get help with a program I've been working on for hours now.

Anyway my issue happens to be with initializing my "sum" variable in a way so that it is not equal a number or become an input. (It's set to equal 0 in my program)

I also seem to be struggling with my while loop statement as I can't think of a condition in which I don't cause the program to terminate or cause a infinite loop.

Any help at this point would highly appreciated.

[image: an example of the program]

Comment: Please post your code into the question instead of an image. It helps others to copy/paste your code to try themselves, if necessary.

Comment: Your loop will exit when your input is 0.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you are trying to compute sum of integers from 1 to n, where n is input from the user.

One of the simpler ways to do that is to use a `for` loop as below

```
for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    sum = sum + i;
}
```

or using `while` loop

```
while(input > 0) {
    sum = sum + input;
    input = input - 1;
}
```

Alternatively, sum of first N natural numbers is given by formula `n*(n+1)/2`, so you might as well do

```
int sum = (n * (n+1))/2;
```

Ensure that n is a positive number > 0 through an if conditional

Answer (score 0):

your While loop is going infinity as your input is never 0 until you give it.
So you have to deal with your input.
Possibly use or declare `input=0` so that when your while loop goes for the execution for 2nd Time...It finds 0.
Hope this helps...Please share doubts if any.